# Unable to Detect face with opencv without using MS cognitive face api in c#

Tags: c#, opencv, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to detect face from video frame with Open cv. I found different- different algorithm like as "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml", "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml", "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml" etc and tried them one by one. But these are not able to get good result. 
    As when there is no face in particular frame at that time it also give me rectangle, while when I am using same frame for detect face with MS cognitive face api, then it gives right result.
   But I need to use Open CV to detect the face from frames and then pass to MS cognitive service to get the face attributes from api. I had done like this:

```
    private readonly OpenCvSharp.CascadeClassifier _localFaceDetector = new OpenCvSharp.CascadeClassifier(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml"));

  var detectedFace = _localFaceDetector.DetectMultiScale(frame.Image); // Detect face by open cv

        if (detectedFace.Count() <= 0)
            return new LiveCameraResult { Faces = null };

      **// Error:(detectedFace) It return rectangle of any objects rather than face**

        // Encode image. 
        var jpgImage = frame.Image.ToMemoryStream(".jpg", s_jpegParams);

        // Submit image to API. 
        var faces = await _faceAnalysis.GetFacesDetection(jpgImage);

        if (faces.Faces.Count() > 0)
        {
              /// Detect face by MS cognitive service
        }
```

Comment: Don't put images of code in question - put the actual code.

Comment: okay let me edit it

Comment: You have to play with parameters of `_localFaceDetector.DetectMultiScale `  to improve the results. Also do histogram equalisation before passing it to the detection function. depends on what the images look like. MS cognitive probably uses Deep learning. You wont get that level of accuracy with Haar.

Comment: @harshkn yes, I had do that. But I need to detect the face from frame. I mean to say that I need to get whether face is present in frame or not.

Comment: Yes, that is the best that haar can get you. Also I cannot say for sure without looking at the images. If you want better try using dlib face detector. [dlib python](http://dlib.net/face_detector.py.html). Check if you can compile this for C#. If you want even better result try a CNN trained for face detection. (slower and more accurate)